# dropdown in chrome extension with js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, drop-down-menu

I've been looking everywhere and can't seem to make this work , when am trying to add a dropdown in chrome extension for my project,it shows error. I tried with all functions(addEventListener , #Id option:selected , onclick) there is no use.

Answer (score 0):

Please add more info - are you trying to do this in a Content Script, the Popup window or how else?

Also, a code example from your project would add a lot of help in debugging a solution for your problem